# Links on website sometime load below top menu bar instead of in it?

Tags: html, css

Here are two screen shots of the website menu bar. The first is how it should look and the second is how it loads about 60% of the time. The other 40%, it loads the correct way.

[image]

[image]

Top Menu Bar Div

```
#top_bar {
    width: 100%;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    background: #ffffff; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

Menu Button Container Div

```
#buttons {
   padding-top: 60px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   float:right;
   font-size: 110%;
}
```

Button

```
 .button-link {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #000000 !important;
    /*margin-left: 0px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

I don't understand why the error only happens some of the time. This error occurs in chrome, but not in safari. If any one can offer some insight as to how I can fix it, that would be great.

Comment: Checked the console for any errors? Do you have any JavaScript on the page or other included files that might be the cause?

Comment: can you show the HTML as well?  Is the "menu button container div" in the "top menu bar div" or?

Comment: It would help if you could post a fiddle with more code so that we can see it working. however, I would start by removing `margin: 0 auto;` from `#buttons` and give it a width.